# Not able to display image in web browser

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

SignupServlet

```
public class SignupServlet extends HttpServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String DIR = "Nanyang Polytechnic/FYPJ Project2/FYPJ/WebContent/profile";
//private static final String SAVE_DIR="images";

// configuration to get Image file name
private String extractFileName(Part part){
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s :items){
        if(s.trim().startsWith("filename")){
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=")+2, s.length()-1);
        }   
    }
    return "";
}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */

public SignupServlet() {
    super();    
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


        //configuration for declaring file saving path  

        //String relativeWebPath = "/profile";
        //String savePath =   getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
        String savePath = "D:" + File.separator + DIR ;

        File fileSaveDir=new File(savePath);
        if(!fileSaveDir.exists()){
              fileSaveDir.mkdir();
          }



        // Configuration to generate Random passsword  
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(900000) + 100000;
        String Password = Integer.toString(num);
        //End


        String Name = request.getParameter("name");
        String Email = request.getParameter("email");
        String UserType = request.getParameter("usertype");
        String strDOB = request.getParameter("dob");
        String Gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");



        Part part = request.getPart("file");
        String fileName = extractFileName(part);

        String filePath = savePath + File.separator + fileName;
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);


        java.sql.Date d;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf;
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date d2 = null;

        try{
            d2 = sdf.parse(strDOB);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        d = new java.sql.Date(d2.getTime());

        DBAO dbao = null;
        Login login = null;




        //configuration for url for image
        /*FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis); 
        BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        for (int data; (data = bis.read()) > -1;){
            output.write(data);
        }
         */


        try {      


            // configuration for email
            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
                String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                String port = "465";
                String fromEmail = "lookeverybodysg@gmail.com";
                String username = "lookeverybodysg";
                String password = "catdog1234";

                props.put("mail.smtp.user", fromEmail);
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");


                Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("lookeverybodysg", "catdog1234"); // username and password
                    }
                });
                mailSession.setDebug(true);

                Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);


            dbao = new DBAO();

                if (dbao.emailExists(Email)){


                    request.setAttribute("Name", Name);
                    request.setAttribute("Email", Email);
                    request.setAttribute("UserType", UserType);
                    request.setAttribute("strDOB", strDOB);
                    request.setAttribute("Gender", Gender);
                    request.setAttribute("Pic", filePath);
                    request.setAttribute("Address", address);


                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">"); 
                    out.println("alert('The email you have used has already been regietered.');");
                    out.println("location='Login.jsp#signup';");
                    out.println("</script>"); 
                    return;
                }else{
                    login = new Login();
                    login.setName(Name);
                    login.setEmail(Email);
                    login.setPassword(Password);
                    login.setUserType(UserType);
                    login.setDOB(d);
                    login.setGender(Gender);
                    login.setPic(filePath);
                    login.setAddress(address);

                    boolean isUserSaved = dbao.saveNewUser(login);

                if (isUserSaved){
                    mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("lookeverybodysg@gmail.com"));
                    mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(Email));
                    mailMessage.setSubject("Thank You for signing up to LookEveryBody!");
                    mailMessage.setContent("Email :" + Email + "<br> Password :" + Password, "text/html");

                    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
                    transport.connect (host, 465, username, password);

                    transport.send(mailMessage);

                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">"); 
                    out.println("alert('Your accout has been successfully created, please go to your email to get your password.');");
                    out.println("location='Login.jsp';");
                    out.println("</script>"); 
                    return;
                }

            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

hairstylistprofile.jsp (display image page code)

```
  <a class="image fit"><img src="<%=login.getPic() %>" alt="" /></a>
```

I was not able to view my image in any of the web browser(google chrome, etcc. However, it can be viewed in the java browser, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value returned by the `login.getPic()`. It seems to me that it contains a value like `D:\path-to-your-image.ext`. The `login.getPic()` should contains a valid url for the image to make it show up in the browser.

If you store your image files outside your web application path, you can create a servlet that read the image file and stream it to the response output. And then use this servlet url as the source for your html image, like `<img src="/picture/profile.jpg"/>`. Use the `<c:url>` taglib to correctly apply the context path of your web application.

```
@WebServlet("/picture/*")
public class ProfilePictureServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String PICTURE_PATH = "D:/Pictures/";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String picture = req.getPathInfo().substring(1); // profile.jpg
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(PICTURE_PATH + picture));
        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

        resp.setContentType("image/jpg");
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: so how can i create a valid url in my servlet? I understand that a browser cannot access a local drive to retrieve and display the image in a browser. However, how should i modified my servlet so that it can display.

Comment: I've update the my answer above.

Comment: so as for the <img> tag i just put src = "profile/ tralala.jpg" ?

Comment: Yes, if your servlet url-pattern is `/profile/*` then every request prefixed with that url-pattern will be handled by the `ProfilePictureServlet` servlet.  The image filename `tralala.jpg` will be obtained from the `request.getPathInfo().substring(1)`.

Comment: however i still could not display my image, if possible take a look at the code I just upload a new set of code with ur code added into it. Thank you

Comment: I didn't see any changing in your code. Btw, if you create the `ProfilePictureServlet` you can access it like `http://localhost:8080/picture/profile.jpg` it will show the image in your browser. Make sure you also have the `profile.jpg` under the `D:/Pictures` directory, where the servlet will look for the image file.

Comment: @BalusC I didn't use any `getRealPath()` method in the code above. Which line in the answer that indicate that?

Comment: Sorry, I misread that.